# Is it possible to have 2 user inputs concatinated to create a list name which is then utilised in a while if in loop?

Tags: python, string, while-loop, format, concatenation

I'm new to Python so as far as I'm concerned it looks like it should work but perhaps I'm confusing myself with the formatting. I have a number of different lists which each have an x and y variable and I need to be able to see if z is in one of these lists. All variables are user inputted and I'm using a formatted string for the xy variable to be put into the if in loop.

```
command = ""

while command != "Stop":
    x = input("x = ")
    y = input("y = ")
    xy = f'{x}_{y}'
    z = input("z = ")
    if z in x_y:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

The While loop works because I can manually enter the list name in place of x_y and I'll get a correct answer. But when using the xy concatenation it returns false every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the built-in function [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) to access the list. Look at the following example:

```
command = ""
test_list = ['foo', 'bar']
while command != "Stop":
    x = input("x = ")
    y = input("y = ")
    xy = f'{x}_{y}'
    z = input("z = ")
    if z in globals()[xy]:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

We can condense the code further by moving the formated string inside of the globals call:

```
globals()[f'{x}_{y}']
```